# Get LocalStorage from an iFrame that I'm injecting into a webpage using my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm injecting an iFrame into a webpage using a Chrome Extension. The iFrame's source is another webpage that I built and it's just a basic To Do list that stores the To Dos in localstorage.

I'd like to be able to access these To Dos in Local Storage inside of my Chrome Extension (either inside a background script or a content script).

I'm slightly confused on how to do this though, since window.localStorage only gives me access to the page's localStorage.

If I check on chrome's console and look at LocalStorage on the Application Tab, I can see the To Dos from the iFrame's localStorage.

[image: Image showing Chrome Console]

As you can see, on google.com, the xxxx.github.io tab is the localStorage for the app I built and there are the associated todos as values.

I'd like to be able to access that localStorage data in my chrome extension. But, whenever I use window.localStorage, I only get access to the "https://www.google.com" key,value pairs.

Is it possible to access the key,value pairs for other sites?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To have a content script running inside the iframe you need to declare it with "all_frames":true ([documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#frames)) or manually inject into the iframe using its internal id.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Use window.parent.postMessage("message", "*") to send a message from the iFrame to the parent window.

Then, add a message Listener in your content script to listen for messages.